Illustrator - Making object transparent
I'm brand new to Illustrator and I'm really struggling.
Ultimately, I'm  trying to create an SVG file, where the white is transparent.  I'm really struggling.  Can anyone sent some tips along?
And, how to I upload a photo of what I'm working on????

If there's a white background, you need to delete it. If you've layered white objects on top of other colors you need to somehow subtract these shapes from what they cover. Exactly how is impossible to tell without knowing what your artwork looks like.

You can reduce the fill opacity to less than 100% in the Appearance Panel, and also in the Properties panel available in more recent versions of Illustrator.
Note that you wont be able to see this opacity change if the fill is white and the page is also white. To see it you can do View > Show Transparency Grid
Here's an example where I've reduced the opacity of a fill to 50%, and enabled the transparency grid to make it visible.

